# How to avoid external calls to change the thread of the stream

Tags: rx-java2

## Problem

I'm facing an issue when using a third party library that spawns a new thread and return values using that new thread. It changes the thread of the whole chain downstream.

## Code

The code would be something like this, it calls a use case and subscribes on a specific scheduler:

```java
someUseCase()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe(value -> print("value emitted: " + value))
```

and inside the use case there will be many operations, including a call to a third party library:

```java
Completable.defer(() -> {
    print("Operations on the chain before calling third party lib");
    return Completable.complete();
})
.andThen(callThirdPartyLib())
.flatMap((Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>) s -> {
    print("Operations on the chain after calling third party lib");
    return Observable.just(s);
})
```

## Current output

The logs would look like this, notice how the thread changes:

```
[Thread: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] Operations on the chain before calling third party lib
[Thread: ThirdPartyLibThread] Operations on the chain after calling third party lib
[Thread: ThirdPartyLibThread] value emitted: third party value new thread
```

## Expected output

I would like the stream to keep operating on the thread that it was originally subscribed on.

## Expected answers

I know that I can fix it adding `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` after calling the third party lib. But I don't want to hardcode the scheduler inside the UseCase class.

I want the user of the class to choose which scheduler they want it subscribed on, without side effects of changing threads in the middle. I could request the scheduler as parameter to the UseCase class, but I'm looking for different alternatives.

## Extra code

This is how the third party lib is called, using the example given in the [javadocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe-):

```java
private static Observable<String> callThirdPartyLib() {
    ThirdPartyLib thirdPartyLib = new ThirdPartyLib();
    return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<String>) emitter -> thirdPartyLib.getData(emitter::onNext))
            //.observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // <-- this fixes it
}
```

This is to simulate a third party lib that call the callback on a different thread - this code can't be changed:

```java
private static class ThirdPartyLib {

    void getData(Callback callback) {
        new Thread(() -> callback.onDataReceived("third party value new thread"), "ThirdPartyLibThread").start();
    }

    interface Callback {
        void onDataReceived(String data);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the client would use the usecase like `useCase.execute().observeOn(Schedulers.io())`?

Comment: my understanding is that observeOn only operates downstream so the operations after the call to the third party lib would still be done on the new thread